# Through APIs: How to get publicly sharable link of a Facebook Album that is locked or set to private?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there a way to get the **public** *link of a Facebook Album* through the **Facebook API** (graph/fql) that can be shared with those who are not on Facebook?

This Album is not publicly accessible. It is restricted by the share permissions on the album set by the user. But I am looking for a way to generate the public link of this restricted album so whoever is sent this link can view the album unconditionally.

*I know this is possible* through the **Share Album** feature on the Facebook website through the Share Dialog: You can send this album to friends or relatives by giving them a link.

I couldn't find a way to to this in the Graph API.

EDIT: I'm talking about the public link that is available through this feature on facebook: facebook.com/help/124590517619792

Comment: Doesn't look like its possible. But it's likely I could stand corrected.

Comment: Yeah this might not be possible, as it would probably mean requiring consent from the user through a UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide an example or test case, nor any API code to work with. I'll use the following links for Facebook User Name **Hostess** as an example (*long live Twinkies!*).:

**Main: https://www.facebook.com/Hostess**
**Photo Album: https://www.facebook.com/Hostess/photos_albums**

First, we will need the Facebook User *Number*.
You can perform a `GET` request or type this into the browser:
**Facebook User Info: http://graph.facebook.com/Hostess**

To continue with this example, we will use the Facebook Number provided by the previous step:
**Facebook ID: [145369525544570](https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=145369525544570)**

> Is there a way to get the public link of a Facebook Album through the
>   Facebook API (graph/fql) that can be shared with those who are not on
>   Facebook?

Yes there's a way! This link will provide you with `json` results for all albums, in this case 6:
**Facebook Albums via `json`: http://graph.facebook.com/145369525544570/albums**

To limit the returned results, you can use `?limit=1` (where 1 is the amount of albums returned):
**Facebook Album (1) via `json`: http://graph.facebook.com/145369525544570/albums?limit=1**

> This Album is not publicly accessible. It is restricted by the share
>   permissions on the album set by the user. But I am looking for a way
>   to generate the public link of this restricted album so whoever is
>   sent this link can view the album unconditionally.

Your out of luck and there isn't a way. However, you don't have to be a Facebook Member to view the images in the Album. Using the `json` data from the previous step works **when the Album is made public.** Just use a simple `GET` request:

[**jsFiddle DEMO: Facebook Albums Links from Facebook ID**](http://jsfiddle.net/GPuH7/)

```js
// Console log messages are provided, activate your browsers console.

$.ajax({
  url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/145369525544570/albums',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(yourVar) {

    // Make sure the request, 1 json object, was returned.
    if (yourVar) {

      console.log('This is the jQuery Object received. Click on it to explore contents');
      console.log(yourVar);

      // This will parse the Objects received in 'data' variable.
      // Having said that, it's coincidental the data the wrapped in a 'data' name.
      $(yourVar.data).each(function(index) {

        // Only process Objects that have valid Album links.
        // Having said that, only Photo Albums are returned in initial data, not Video Albums.
        if(this.link){

          // Display in console the jQuery zero indexed number
          console.info('Album Index object: ' + index);
          //
          // Display in HTML via append, the same information.
          $('body').append('<b>Album Index Object: </b>' + index + '<br />');


          // Display in console the Album Names available
          console.info('Name: ' + this.name);
          //
          // Display in HTML via append, the same information.
          $('body').append('<b>Name: </b>' + this.name + '<br />');


          // Display in console the Album Name Url;
          console.log('Url: ' + this.link);
          //
          // Display in HTML via append, the same information.
          $('body').append('<b>Url: </b>' + this.link + '<br />');


          // Display in console dashed lines before next item is shown.
          console.log('-------');
          //
          // Display in HTML via append, the same information.
          $('body').append('<hr><br /><br />');

        }

      });

    } else {
        console.log('Was data expected? Check your jQuery or JavaScript for errors.');
    }
  }

});

// Power-Tip!
// You can also use .ajax() with a YQL Rest Query url.
// See YQL Console with Rest Statement at: 
// http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=SELECT%20data.link%20FROM%20json%20WHERE%20url%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.facebook.com%2F145369525544570%2Falbums%22&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys
// As seen there, the   data.link   is providing just the links.
// Change   data.link   to   *   to see all data nodes available in json tree.
// That being said, your .ajax() url for above is at the bottom: The Rest Query.
```

Comment: This album link from the graph api is not publicly accessible. It is restricted by the share permissions on the album. What I'm looking for is probably not possible through the apis as it would mean requiring consent from the user through a UI.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question, I've up voted your answer. However I'm looking to see if there is a way to programmatically achieve the functionality of the share album dialog.

Comment: @Rajesh: Fortunately this is not possible, otherwise it's a embarrassing **Security Hole** that Facebook would be unaware of. See Edit in my answer with Facebook Documentation explaining their privacy settings. Thanks!

Comment: It wouldn't be Security Hole if it required explicit user consent through a UI dialog (similar to the app requesting permissions during oAuth), but that is probably beyond the scope of the apis I guess :).

Comment: But you mentioned that it's for *non-Facebook members*, hence a Token Key *is* required.

Comment: This is a real scenario that my app would ideally like to support. Suppose a user uploads a bunch of photos to his facebook album through my app and he would like to share the public link of that album to his friends via email. I would like to support this scenario through the app instead of having to generate the public link by visiting facebook.com. But yeah, this is not probably a good use case for an API to tackle and has to be done by user through facebook site.

Comment: You wrote *"share the public link of that album"* which I show how in the bottom portion of my answer. To be clear, if it's locked, it's locked.

Comment: Also consider the YQL example above: It's a direct link to photos that are set to private. That in itself states you have the link, *the public link to the photos*, except you need a key... the *Facebook Token Key*, to access it since *the content is what's private*, not the link per se.

Comment: I'm talking about the public link that is available through this feature: http://www.facebook.com/help/124590517619792/

Comment: The section in my answer titled "When the Album is not locked" shows how to discover the Facebook Album URL to share with non-members. Also, when you hover over an Album in the browser, you can copy it's location with the clipboard.

Comment: The link available through the above feature is public in the sense that whoever has that link can view the album and need not be Facebook members even though the album itself is locked/private.

Comment: I think you've mixed settings between private and public. For a simple test, set a Album to private (lock it), then share it to me as a non-facebook member so I can analyze the results. To be sure, the YQL tool above helps to discover if content is accessible or not.

Comment: The above feature does not seem to work anymore. Looks like a recent change as these users have noted here: http://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10151200793454472

Comment: **I've illustrated in my Answer that sharing of Albums is possible. Please provide with an actual Facebook Album to test for which your having issues with, as I see none.**

Comment: This feature used to work for sharing private or public albums as others have noted in the discussion thread.

Comment: Above in my answer, it works without issue. Use the YQL Console to see.

Comment: The answer is **it can't be done**, as I mention in my Answer in the Edit section.

Comment: If my answer address your Question, please Accept it.

Comment: It doesnt. My question has to do with this feature facebook.com/help/124590517619792
and the link I'm talking about is the one discussed here:
 facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10151200793454472
 and not what the one that your method provides.
Your link is only good for public albums and not private.

Comment: Your question reflects Facebook API and Facebook's FQL, but to be sure, I've provided references and examples to satisfy your Question.

Answer (score 0):

### *In Detail: Why it can't be done. (otherwise it's a security issue!!!)*

**Facebook Settings for Photos and Albums:**
[*When I share something, how do I choose who can see it?*](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=120939471321735)

The above Facebook documentation states that if a Album is set to Private via **Only Me**, then it will only be available to you, ***even though you may have a shareable link for it.***

To demonstrate that the Album/Photos is indeed locked and not shareable, here is an actual live test using **Yahoo! Query Language** to perform a request on a locked photo album:

[image]

Feel free to click the image to visit the above YQL Statement.

To be sure, the above example in itself shows that the link is not the issue, it's **the content** that is really the subject, as that's the item locked for which a Facebook Token key is required.